How would I get a users PROFILE PICTURE FILE NAME ONLY and call it after the user interacts with a button?
My current code defines a button that has a interaction response, and puts some of the users information in a URL, like their id, name, dprofile picture, etc. I want to fix my code so that it gets the users profile picture FILE NAME ONLY, when they click the interaction button, and then the link. So i can put just the filename into the URL.
The code looks something like this right now:
view.add_item(discord.ui.Button(label="Test", url=test_url.format(user=str(interaction.user.avatar.filename) 

there is a button, and this adds another label, and when clicking this button it obtains the users name and id which is not shown here, but I want it to also collect just the users profile picture image filename only, just the file name.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please provide what the test_url template looks like. Maybe the problem is easier than you thought. Also just checked and member.avatar object doesn't have a filename attribute.
Discord saves profile images with your id and a long sequence of numbers followed by a size info which is exponents of 2. So I don't know what is the point of getting the filename it's literally a sequence of random numbers. Here's an example:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/951142187444363364/0c8e6037c85644671549a85d28ff993b.png?size=1024
The member.avatar object has quite a few good options to use aswell one of them being the url to the avatar.
return interaction.user.avatar.url #Returns the url to the avatar image with size=1024

